# How to add popup message on disabled button while hovering in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a submit button in my form which is enabled if the form is valid, otherwise, it will be on disable state. I want to add a popup message on hover over the disabled button not enabled button. How to add it dynamically in angularjs?

Comment: You're going to need something like [Bootstrap's Tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#examples) to get this to work. Then dynamically add/remove the attributes based on the state of your form. You could also try the JS functionallity from BS

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a decent tooltip, if it's not to your liking, feel free to use another, tho when writing a directive it will be different. 
I prefer this over writing your own tooltip module since this way you have a tested and robust way to display tooltips anywhere.

Then you are gonna want to wrap it as a directive to work in AngularJS like:

```
app.directive('tooltip', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.hover(function(){
                // on mouseenter
                element.tooltip('show');
            }, function(){
                // on mouseleave
                element.tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now you have a tooltip that is styled and should work when attached to any element. Attach it to the said button:

```
<button tooltip="myTooltip">I am a button</button>
```

**NOTE:** If disabled prevents it from showing (didn't test that) then simply wrap that button in a `<span></span>` and bind tooltip to that span instead since span is not disabled.

```
<span tooltip="myTooltip"><button>I am a button</button></span>
```

In any case, either you bind directly to button or span around it, don't forget in the controller for that view, set the tooltip text:

```
$scope.myTooltip = 'Tooltip text';
```